# How do I change the date format from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in libreoffice calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet with existing date values that I'd like to convert from MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY format. Is there any way of doing this?

The spreadsheet comes from a csv file from someone else that i have opened in calc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the format of the cells?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yep, doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Are you  sure these are dates and not text that looks like dates?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad hmmm, they could be text. how would i know? i never work with spreadsheets/calc so i'm a bit out of my depth here...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad okay, looks like they are def text values...

Comment: Where do the values comes from? Did you enter them by hand, imported them from a CSV or so, got the spreadsheet from someone else? -- Would you mind to post one of these values? You might try to copy-paste it, or only if that does *not* resemble the value as shown in Calc, provide a (small) screenshot. -- Please [edit] your question, don't add information down here in the comments.

Comment: @thebusybee copy/pasting looks the same as it does in Calc. Have added the rest to the question.

Comment: When you opened the CSV in Calc you are asked about the columns format. Did you try to set the data type of `payment_date` to "date"? -- Would you mind to provide a few lines of the CSV file, or at least some excerpt of it that includes `payment_date`? Obviously you would like to edit some sensitive values, and to limit the number of fields. You can open the CSV file with any text editor.

Comment: @thebusybee I included a screenshot in the question. i'll add another one now with the box that pops up when i open the file before i click "ok"

Comment: Try using "English US" as the language(`MM/DD/YYYY` is the US date format) and/or activating "Detect Special Numbers"

Comment: OK, where the "Fields" are shown, you should be able to change from "Standard" to "Date". -- Concerning the CSV file excerpt, you can use gedit to open it. I think that you're running Ubuntu, right?

Comment: @thebusybee yes, ubuntu. i can change it to date and then select DMY but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Now I'm really curious about to see the values in the CSV file.

Comment: @thebusybee if it's a text value is there no way of making a function that swaps the day/month around?

Comment: Sure, but I'd like to get something to experiment with. Without seeing what your CSV file contains *exactly* we'll be guessing all night. That's clearly a waste of time for both of us. And at my place it's time to go to bed now. :-} Please try to provide an excerpt of the CSV file. As I said, you may use any text editor to open it, and to remove all but a few lines, and to protect the sensitive data. See you tomorrow morning.

Comment: The tip was gold, when opening the CSV in Calc, select column(s) with dates and change from Standard to Date, worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

1. Select the cells with the dates and in `Cell -> Format`, choose the date format you wish (`DD/MM/YYYY`)
2. Making sure the cells are selected, go to `Data -> Text to columns` choose "Separated by" and "Tab" and click "OK"

Cells should now have the desired format

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you follow the steps to the end? works fine on my machine

Comment: 2. is the step I coudn't figure out on my own

Answer (score 10):

1. Cut (or copy then erase) all values from the column (CTRL + X).
2. Choose Edit -> Paste Special -> Unformatted text (MAJ + CTRL + ALT + V).
3. On "Fields", note the word "standard" appears at the head of each column (e.g. in the screenshot in the original question). Right-click on your date column heading, then select "Date (MDY)". **It is important here to select the format the data currently is, NOT the format you want it to be.**

If date is still not OK, you will need to follow this additional step (response above from @cybernetic.nomad):

> 4. Select the cells with the dates and in Cell -> Format, choose the date format you wish (DD/MM/YYYY).

NB: Note that my LibreOffice Calc is not in english so I am not 100% sure about the option names.

Comment: << On "Fields" >> here, you lost me.  Where is that "Fields" widget?

Comment: @HansDeragon : if you cut (CTRL + X) then Unformatted text paste (MAJ + CTRL + ALT + V), a window called "Text import", similar to the one shown on Steve question, should appear. "Fieds" is located on this window.

Comment: This is the best answer as it recognises that the problem lies in the difference between A) getting LibreOffice to recognise the format of the date in the paste buffer, rather than B) just formatting a date which is presumed to be correct.

Comment: e.g. imagine the date was meant to be 4th May 2024 but is entered numerically in a csv and then imported/pasted into LibreOffice as 5/4/2024. IF Libre Office expects a European date then it will give it the numeric code 45387 meaning 5th April 2024 and then there is no way you can reformat it to make any sense. There seems a limited window of opportunity to get it to recognise the raw format when it is pasted in and if you forget then you have to resort to BusyBee's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You select the cells to format, then you press Ctrl-1 (or choose "Format" - "Cells..." from the menu, or any other way) to open the dialog to format cells. There is a text field "Format code" where you enter "DD/MM/YYYY" without the quotation marks. Click "OK".

If that does *not* format the date like you want, the value in the cell is not interpretable as a date. Investigate the cell's value, you might have a text marker (a single apostrophe ') as the first character.

To check this out and experiment with the formats, choose "Insert" - "Date" from the menu. It puts the current date into the current cell.

*Disclaimer: Since my Calc is not set to English, the names of menus and their entries might be different. I just guessed how they could be named.*

---

**EDIT:**

If you can't change the cell format because the date is constantly recognized as "text", you might like to try this:

1. Insert a column right from the date column. This produces in your case the column `O`. All columns right of it are pushed to the right.
2. Put this formula in cell `O2` on the right of the first date text:

   ```
   =CONCATENATE(MID(N2;4;3);MID(N2;1;3);MID(N2;7;4))
   ```

   It takes snippets (`MID()`) from cell `N2` and concatenates them in the new order. Details of the functions are in Calc's documentation.

   You will need to adjust `N2` to the correct cell reference if it is *not* the cell directly left of the cell you're entering the formula.
3. Put the cell cursor on `N2`.
4. Press these key combinations in sequence to mark a deep enough range of cells in column `O`: Control-Down, Right, Shift-Control-Up. The cell cursor will be on cell `O2` now, and the range below and including it is marked.
5. Now press Control-D to copy the formula in `O2` into each cell in the range.

Now you will have a new column `O` with the text of `N`, but exchanged characters. The values are still "text", though.

If you like, you can shrink the width of column `N` now, or hide it.

Comment: It looks like it is text and not date values... how can i get the desired format as a text value?

Comment: There are some converter functions. Please see Calc's documentation, or add more information to your question, as I just asked for above.

Answer (score 1):

**Example:**
Input wanted: DD/MM/YYYY (31/12/2021)

Input accepted: MM/DD/YYYY (12/31/2021)

**First add new Date type**

1. Go to Format --> Cells
2. In "Category" select "Date"
3. In "Format code" write the input wanted. In this case DD/MM/YYYY
4. Press the green check

**Second format style**

1. Go in the cell where you want to add the date
2. Write the date in the wrong format. Example: 12/31/2021 (for 31st December 2021) even if you want 21/11/2021
3. Select that cell and press CTRL-X. The text should disappear
4. Select that now empty cell and do: Edit -> Paste Special -> Pase unformatted text
5. The date should be there in the wrong format
6. Select that cell with the wrong date and do: Format --> Cells
7. In "category" select "date" and double click on the newly added date type (aka DD/MM/YYYY)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple of steps:

1. copy the column with the cells in MM/DD/YYYY format - 3/25/2023 and paste it 3 columns, each containing the Month, the Day, the Year

- 3/25/2023 becomes 3 25 2023 (as 3 columns)

2. reverse the order of the Month and the Day columns

- 3 25 2023 becomes 25 3 2023 (still 3 columns)

3. add a slash - / - after the text in the Day and the Month columns

- 25 3 2023 becomes 25/ 3/ 2023  (still 3 columns)

4. combine the 3 columns into one

- 25/ 3/ 2023 becomes 25/3/2023

At step 1) use Edit> Paste Special > Paste Unformatted Text - and in the section "Separated by" use "Other" and in the textbox put a slash - / - to be used as a separator.

At step 3) to add a slash after the text in the cells, select the text column and right-click > Format cells and inside the "Format Code" field put a << quote slash quote >> e.g.: "/" - so the field will be:  General"/"
Do this for the Day and the Month columns

At step 4) to combine the Day, Month and Year columns into one, copy the 3 adjacent columns and paste them inside a single column, using Edit> Paste Special > Paste Unformatted Text - and in the section "Separated by" use Space (the default value, I think)